# What can go wrong if operators have side-effects?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, side-effects

I came across a Python library that defines a class analogous to the following, where the `>>` operator is overloaded to have a global side-effect:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class V(object):
    """A Vertex in a graph."""

    graph = defaultdict(list)  # accessed globally

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __rshift__(self, other):
        V.graph[self].append(other)
        return other

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'V(%r)' % (self.label,)
```

The library does this because "it gives the user some nice syntax" for symbolically building up networks, by writing down simple expressions such as:

```
a = V('a')
b = V('b')
c = V('c')
a >> b >> c >> c
```

in order to build a network where `a` is connected to `b`, which is connected to `c`, which is recurrently connected to itself.

There is similar machinery within the `+`, `*`, and `@` operators as well. All of this behaviour is documented and to be expected by the user.

However, are there any strange things that could happen, where you wouldn't think the expression should be evaluated—but actually is—or vice-versa? That is, does the execution model for Python ever assume that certain expressions are free from any side-effects? I want to know if there is any precedent, or whether any special precautions need to be taken by the user.

Comment: It smells terrible to me.

Comment: What can happen is that it behaves unexpectedly. Because who would expect that? And unexpected behaviour is ... well ... wrong. As for expecting side-effects or not, I don't think Python expects anything, but developers do.

Comment: @zvone: To help clarify, it should be expected by the users because this is the way of "connecting" things together with this library. This syntax and use-case is central to all of their examples and documentation, and so all users will be aware of this behaviour. My question was more about whether this might have unintended consequences that the developers did not consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked specifically about unexpected evaluation or non-evaluation. Python does not assume that any user-defined operators are side-effect-free, so it won't skip an `a >> b` on the bad assumption that it doesn't do anything. People occasionally have problems when they assume that certain functions don't do certain things - for example, assuming that a function that takes an iterable won't try `len` - but most such problems would hold equally for `>>` or a method.

You might get problems with alternative interactive environments making assumptions - for example, I can imagine having problems with tab completion trying to evaluate things it shouldn't - but using the module in an actual Python program should not have such problems.

The closest thing I'd expect to such problems in an actual program would be precedence problems. For example, C++'s use of `<<` for printing leads to problems like the following code:

```
std::cout << true ? "a" : "b";
```

[which prints `1`](https://ideone.com/sFZVH4) instead of `a` because `<<` binds tighter than `?:`. I can imagine similar problems arising with this library.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any other Python library that does this.

One example of something weird or unexpected, to me, is the following:

```
a = V('a')
b = V('b')

def do_something(c=a>>b):
    return c>>c

do_something(a)
```

This might be considered to give a weird result (`a >> a` and `a >> b`) since the default argument is evaluated, regardless of whether it ends up being used.

---

As another example, when using `try`/`except`, any partially completed evaluation will result in an incomplete set of side-effects that cannot be rewound.

```
try:
    a >> b >> c
except NameError:
    # do something else
```

Here, the error-handling might need to cope with the fact that `a >> b` was still evaluated.

---

I'm not recommending that users do either of these things. I'm only claiming that if a user were to do this, then they might get behaviour that is surprising, unexpected, or difficult for them to debug.

Comment: Off the top of my head, [pyparsing uses `<<` with side effects for forward references](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).